# xslt set node value in parent group

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Sample XML input file:

```
<sample>    
    <vars>    
        <var>    
            <name>connection1</name>    
            <value>tcp</value>    
        </var>    
        <var>    
            <name>connection2</name>    
            <value>ssl</value>    
        </var>    
    </vars>    
</sample>
```

Having looked at other questions answered, i have not seen an example that i am able to use. I wish to process the above xml file to edit a node value depending on the name node.

e.g. find name=connection1 and set the value that is in the same group to SSL

Output

```
 <sample>    
    <vars>    
        <var>    
            <name>connection1</name>    
            <value>ssl</value>    
        </var>    
        <var>    
            <name>connection2</name>    
            <value>ssl</value>    
        </var>    
    </vars>    
</sample>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the shortest solution and for an explanation of the most fundamental XSLT design pattern -- the identity rule pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Probably the shortest solution is this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "var[name='connection1']/value/text()">ssl</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<sample>
    <vars>
        <var>
            <name>connection1</name>
            <value>tcp</value>
        </var>
        <var>
            <name>connection2</name>
            <value>ssl</value>
        </var>
    </vars>
</sample>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<sample>
   <vars>
      <var>
         <name>connection1</name>
         <value>ssl</value>
      </var>
      <var>
         <name>connection2</name>
         <value>ssl</value>
      </var>
   </vars>
</sample>
```

**Explanation**:

**This solution uses the most fundamental XSLT design pattern: the use of the [identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** to copy every node as-is and its overriding by a template matching a specific node that only needs to be changed.

Comment: excellent, bit of a newbie to xslt, this is exactly what im after,

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="var[name = 'connection1']/value">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:text>ssl</xsl:text>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="value[preceding-sibling::name = 'connection1']">
    <value>ssl</value>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an [XSL Identity Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) along with a template that processes your specific case and substitutes ssl for tcp.